# How to Convert Oracle Sql to Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle11g

My SQL query has "connect by regexp_substr". How do I convert it to PostgreSQL 10 query ?

I have tried this in Ubuntu and toad...

```sql
  select regexp_substr('1,2,4','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('1,2,4', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

How to do I get convert above query to PostgreSQL version 10?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to split a comma-delimited string into rows.  For that, use `regexp_split_to_table()`:

```
select regexp_split_to_table('1,2,4', ',')
```

In Postgres, it is possible that you would really phrase the overall query using arrays.  If you have a question about a larger query, ask in a *new* question.

Answer (score 2):

`string_to_array()` is typically faster if no regular expression is needed.

```
select *
from unnest(string_to_array('1,2,4', ',')) as t(c);
```